# Understanding this algorithm to find permutations of a string (recursion)

Tags: java, algorithm

I was going through my textbook, and I couldn't really wrap my head around how this generates the permutations of a string recursively

```
class PermutationIterator
{
    private String wrd;
    private int current;
    private PermutationIterator Iter;
    private String tl;
    // Constructor
    public PermutationIterator(String s)
    {
        wrd = s;
        current = 0;
        if (wrd.length() > 0)
            Iter = new PermutationIterator(wrd.substring(1));
    }

    public String nextPermutation()
    {
        if(wrd.length() == 0)
        {
            current++;
            return "";
        }

        char c = wrd.charAt(current);
        String nextPermut = Iter.nextPermutation();
        if(!Iter.hasMorePermutations())
        {
            System.out.println("Current value is " + current + " word length is " + wrd.length());
            current++;
            if (current >= wrd.length()) {
                Iter = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (current + 1 >= wrd.length())
                    tl = wrd.substring(0,current);
                else
                    //System.out.println("Reached");
                    tl = wrd.substring(0,current) + wrd.substring(current + 1, wrd.length());
                    Iter = new PermutationIterator(tl);
            }
        }
        return c + nextPermut;
    }

    public boolean hasMorePermutations()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside this method we have current= " + current + " with wrdlength "  + wrd.length() +"with the word " + wrd);
        return current < wrd.length();
    }
}
```

This gets called by

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        PermutationIterator iter = new PermutationIterator("eat");
        while(iter.hasMorePermutations())
        {
            System.out.println(iter.nextPermutation());
        }
    }
```

For `eat` this will output

`eat 
eta
aet
ate
tea
tae`

**My attempt**

Before even attempting to understand everything, for the past three days I have been really struggling to figure out how exactly `!Iter.hasMorePermutations()` is reached. The only way this can be false is if  `return current < wrd.length();` is not true. i.e `wrd.length() <= current`.

Now here is where it really starts to lose me. I tried printing out the values of word.length and current inside the  `!Iter.hasMorePermutations()` branch just to see what was going on.

`Current value is 0 word length is 1
Current value is 0 word length is 2
eat`

Wait.. How is this possible? Isn't our condition for reaching this branch, to have current value bigger than our word length? How did we ever reach this branch?

I have also attached a picture of my trying to trace the program,[image]

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: YOu should add the caller of PermutationIterator (main method). Or in other words - where is `nextPermutation` being called?

Comment: Added sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

There are four iterators active at a time, for each of the word lengths. They all have their own values of `current`, and the call to `hasMorePermutations` is checking the values of `current` and `length` on the next iterator, not itself. So you may want to instead output:

```
System.out.println("Current value is " + Iter.current + " word length is " + Iter.wrd.length());
```

To start with, all their current values are 0, so we have for 'eat':

```
(word = 'eat', current = 0, length = 3)
 (word = 'at', current = 0, length = 2)
  (word = 't', current = 0, length = 1)
   (word = '', current = 0, length = 0)
```

Each iterator calls `nextPermutation` on the next, until we get to the last iterator which has its `current` value incremented because `wrd.length() == 0`. So we get:

```
(word = 'eat', current = 0, length = 3)
 (word = 'at', current = 0, length = 2)
  (word = 't', current = 0, length = 1)
   (word = '', current = 1, length = 0)
```

This is detected in the third iterator's `Iter.hasMorePermutations()`, which will then increment its own `current` value and reset the last iterator:

```
(word = 'eat', current = 0, length = 3)
 (word = 'at', current = 0, length = 2)
  (word = 't', current = 1, length = 1)
   (word = '', current = 0, length = 0)
```

This is similarly detected by the second iterator, which resets the last two iterators:

```
(word = 'eat', current = 0, length = 3)
 (word = 'at', current = 1, length = 2)
  (word = 'a', current = 0, length = 1)
   (word = '', current = 0, length = 0)
```

The first iterator's call to `Iter.hasMorePermutations()` will then return false, so it doesn't increment its current value, giving the next String 'eta'.

Comment: I'm a bit confused at `(word = 't', current = 1, length = 1)` in the third Iterator code. I get that we make `current = 1` at the empty `word`, but why does that mean we add `1` to the `current` with word `t`? Where in the code is this?

Comment: @bill It's incremented at `current++` right after `if(!Iter.hasMorePermutations())`, but before the last iterator is recreated.

Comment: `word = '', current = 1, length = 0)` we return "" here so how does if(!Iter.hasMorePermutations()) get reached

Comment: @bill It's not reached from the fourth iterator, but it is from the third one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing are the values of `wrd` and `current` of `this` object, not of the object `Iter` on which `!Iter.hasMorePermutations()` is evaluated.

To understand what is going on you should be printing `Iter.wrd.length()` and `Iter.current`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are missing is that the test isn't `this.hasMorePermutations()`, but rather `Iter.hasMorePermutations()`, possibly confused by the fact that `Iter` looks like a class name rather than a field name...

So, just before your point 3 returns, that has word length 0 and current 1, that is, no more iterations, and when it returns to the parent it is the object being tested, so you enter the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

in your diagram at number 3 ,

it falls into this if branch

```
        if(wrd.length() == 0)
        {
            current++;
            return "";
        }
```

once this branch is executed , now `wrd.length()` is 0 and `current` is 1, 
so after `nextPermutation` hits this if branch, next immediate call to `hasMorePermutations` will return `false`

Answer (score -1):

What's so complicated? The way I read the code and translate into English, the procedure is:

`for(current=0 to string_len)`

1. pick the letter at the position of `current`
2. extract it out from the string (make a string with that letter missing). (this will have a length reduced by one; am I stating the obvious here?)
3. *recursively* generate the permutations of the string so constructed at the prev step (call it `tl`), taking care to add the extracted letter as the first one for each of the permutation generated on the shortened `tl` string

Since when `current` reaches `string_len` there's no more letters to extract, it means you are done.

It's a case of "turtles all the way down" - a 3-letter iterator will use a 2-letter iterator, which will use a 1-letter iterator which will use an empty-string iterator.

At each level, the iterator will extract the `current` letter, create a `level-1` iterator,'squeeze it dry' and discard it when it doesn't have anything to offer. Once `current` is at max, this iterator will report to the `level+1` one that "i'm dry" and get sacked.

--

["Rubber duck debugging"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to understand how `!Iter.hasMorePermutations()` is reached:

**Empty string**

- set current = 0
- extract first letter - I cannot `current == len`, thus:

  1. return empty string first time we are called (and increment current)
  2. when called, tell the caller 'false==hasMorePermutation()'

See

```
    if(wrd.length() == 0)
    {
        current++;
        return "";
    }
```

**Word with 1 letter** - make it "t"

- set current=0
- extract the letter at current - first_letter='t'; `tl`=""
- generate the first permutation of `tl` (empty string) *using an empty string permutation iterator* (see above)

  String nextPermut = Iter.nextPermutation();

only one possible, as it is an empty string. When I, the one-letter-iterator, gets to ask my sub-iterator (the empty string one) "do you have more permutations" the answer will come in the negative

```
    if(!Iter.hasMorePermutations()) 
        // this is true immediately for my empty-str subiterator
```

So, what me, the one-letter-iterator will do?

Will increment my `current` then...

because next time I'll be asked, I won't be able to generate one more, I'll sack my (zero-length) iterator

```
        if (current >= wrd.length()) {
            Iter = null;
        }
```

and then return the extracted letter (my only one) prepended to the permutation generated by my (already sacked) iterator : thus returning a "t" prepended to an empty string.

What I, the one-letter iterator will answer next time I'm asked  `hasMorePermutations`? Well, `false`, because I incremented my `current` to the length of my string (1)

---

Do you really want me to continue, or are you already seeing the 'iterators using iterators for one-less-letter words, each one of those iterators with its own `current` and word'?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain how exactly `!Iter.hasMorePermutations()` is being reached. This is my main confusion Please read my attempt

Comment: Ok. I'll try - stay tuned.